# Type checking a simple Vue.js app with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Vue.js comes with official TypeScript type definitions that are installed along the library with NPM.

I am trying to use them to type check a simple app. All of the samples I've found demonstrate the use of TypeScript in components but I couldn't find a way to type check a simple app like:

```
import * as Vue from 'vue';

interface Item {
    name: string;
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: <Item[]> []
  },
  methods: {
    addItem: function () {
      this.items.push({ name: 'Item' });
    }
  }
});
```

I guess that the main challenge is that all the data, methods, computed properties, etc., should all be available on `this`. However in this case, `this` is of type `Vue` and does not contain an `items` property.

Is there a way to pull this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might help, I am not too familiar with VueJS but try this

```
import * as Vue from 'vue';

interface Item {
   name: string;
}

interface App extends Vue {
   items: Item[];
}

export default {
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: <Item[]> []
  },
  methods: {
    addItem: function () {
      this.items.push({ name: 'Item' });
    }
  }
} as ComponentOptions<App>
```

The alternative is using a peer dependency

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'
// The @Component decorator indicates the class is a Vue component
@Component({
  // All component options are allowed in here
  el: '#app' //... rest of your options
})
export default class Item extends Vue {
  // Initial data can be declared as instance properties
  items: <Item[]> []
  // Component methods can be declared as instance methods
  addItem (): void {
    this.items.push({name: 'Item' });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to adjust the 1st example to make it work (see my edit). However, the 2nd one didn't work for me. I don't have a 'vue-class-component' module to import from, and when I try `import Component from 'vue'`, the compiler complains that Component is not callable.

Comment: Yeah for the second example you'd need to npm install it. The first example has some shortcomings.